# Linked List C Error

Tags: c

I am getting a segmentation fault error when I run this code. I don't get the error when I run it in gdb. I also don't get this error when i < 17.

```
void test() 
{
    struct node *listHead=NULL;
    int i=0;
    while(i<17)
        addTail(&listHead,createNode(i++));
}

struct node* createNode(int i)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    n->item = i;
    return n;
}
void addTail(struct node **listHead, struct node *n)
{
    if(*listHead!= NULL)
    {
        struct node *temp = *listHead;

        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = n;
    } else 
    {
        *listHead= n;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: It's difficult to say, because you haven't given the definition of `insertTail`.

Comment: Who goes round upvoting questions like these?

Comment: What's wrong with the question? It definitely helped me. This is my first time using C and I was stuck with this error. Instead of struggling to figure it out I was able to come here and get an answer within 1 minute.

Comment: It might have helped you, but that doesn't make it a good question!  Your question originally had an incorrect code snippet, and shows no attempt to debug the problem yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not initializing the new elements correctly.

Add `n->next = NULL;` to the `createNode` function.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Why do you have to initialize it to NULL? What is the default

Comment: The standard does not say there is a default initialization for any variable.  If it is not initialized, the data is whatever was left in memory by the last object there.

Comment: `malloc` returns uninitialized data. It does _not_ return zero-filled blocks. Check out `calloc` if you want zero'ed out data.

Comment: Not to mention yasouser's answer of it malloc'ing the wrong size of object

Comment: @Dan F: yarouser's answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Dan F: yasouser's answer is incorrect. The `malloc`ed size is correct as it is in the original code.

Comment: Oh you're right, i misread it as `sizeof(node*)` instead of `sizeof(*n)` which does make sense

Comment: @Hna: There's no "default" for `malloc`ed objects in C language. The `malloc`ed object always contain garbage. You can use `calloc` to initialize memory with all-bits-zero pattern, but it has potential issues of its own. Better just set `next` to `NULL` explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's the fact that you have `insertTail` in the main but `addTail` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're using 'malloc' which does NOT clear(fill with zeros) the memory space it allocates before it hands it back toyour.  In your first case(adding the head), addTail simply makes the newly allocated node the list head, complete with a very probably non-null 'next' field.

1. Try using calloc(1, sizeof(node))